# Why does the upper half plane get mapped inside of the polygon?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

If a conformal mapping, e.g., a Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, maps the real line (from left to right) to a polygon, which is traced out from left to right, why is the upper half plane mapped to the interior of the polygon?

Is it a preservation of orientation argument?  I.e., since the upper half plane was to the "left" of the moving point in the z-plane (moving along the real axis), then the image of the upper half plane will again be to the left of the curve, which is also going from left to right, until it closes at the final vertex to form the polygon.

I know that one can use a test point and then make a connectedness argument, but if the integral (or any tricky conformal mapping) were hard to evaluate, such as an elliptic integral, I don't feel that this is a wise move to make, and that there could possibly be a better way to argue why the image of the UHP is inside the polygon.

Thanks,

Comment: The preservation of orientation argument that you suggest works as written.

Comment: Hi Professor Belk, can I ask you a follow-up question on this?  Why does the argument work?  Is it something to do with "domain preservation" or is that something fancier that I don't need to worry about?

Comment: Basically, I know it's true, because I learned it from an online course (on Coursera) that I no longer seem to have access to.  But the professor teaching the course just stated the idea without proof.  But orientation preservation, I feel, is only relevant to the *interior* of a set, i.e., two curves on the UHP *but not on the boundary, the real axis,* that form an angle alpha, under a conformal mapping will again form an angle alpha in the w-plane, with the two curves oriented in the same direction.  Is this the idea that is being used?  Thanks, @JimBelk.